# Wordpress random blank pages

Tags: wordpress

That's pretty weird...

A testing version of a website running on Wordpress is just giving me blank pages randomly, on home page, when i call category, whatever... It can change, a page can work, then 5 min later, go blank.

.htaccess issue ?

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Nothing special there... Server trouble ? I just got a plugin that manage Custom types / fields.

And well, only on Chrome, on Windows. That wouldn't be fun on all browsers....

The network panel reveals 1 request, the URL I try to access, with status OK (200).

EDIT : No, it doesn't come form wp_head(), it worked for 2min, then displayed blank pages... I putted debug configuration for Wordpress (according to this link : http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) but it shows no error.
So, It doesn't come from PHP, not from server too. I looked up the HTML / JS part : I checked those pages with W3C validator and get fatal error :

```
Line 1, Column 1: Non-space characters found without seeing a doctype first. Expected <!DOCTYPE html>.
```

DAT FCKING UTF-8 WITH BOM.

Comment: Check your error logs.

Comment: You mean, server logs ?

Comment: Yes. It sounds like a PHP error, look in PHP, Apache and MySQL error logs.

Comment: More precisely, it sounds like an out of memory error with display_errors turned off.

Comment: It seems i can't get an access to PHP / MySQL logs... How can I debug it ?

Comment: Well, if it's about PHP / MySQL, how can it works on Firefox and Opera, but not on Chrome (on my desktop, working on my laptop and tablet)?

Comment: Ah, missed that part. In that case it's more likely a problem with the browser, or in the HTML/JavaScript. htaccess can't be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get it ! Finally !
Actually, Wordpress (3.5.1) contained an UTF-8 with BOM encoded file :

```
wp-includes\js\jquery\jquery.query.js
```

I cleaned it, using Emrah Gündüz BOM cleaner (https://github.com/emrahgunduz), written in PHP. I ran it on my local server to check and remove bom from all files. 
Now it works like a charm.